# cross product of a position vector and a vector field

Tags: vector-analysis

The problem is to simplify the following expression: $$\nabla\times[\frac{(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{r})}{r^3}\vec{r}]$$ where $\vec{B}$ is a constant vector and $\vec{r}$ is a position vector.

So $(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{r})$ is scalar product and $\frac{(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{r})}{r^3}$ is a scalar field. Which means the identity $$\nabla \times (\Phi\vec{r}) = \Phi(\nabla\times\vec{r}) - \vec{r}\times(\nabla\Phi)$$ can be applied. And $\Phi = \frac{(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{r})}{r^3}\vec{r}$.

Then $(\nabla\times\vec{r})=0 $ and $\nabla\Phi$ is a vector field $\vec{A}$.

So the expression is left with $-\vec{r}\times\vec{A}$.

The question is: how do I find the cross product between a position vector and a vector field?

Comment: The curl ($\nabla \times \vec{F}$) of a radial vector field of form $\vec{F} = f(r) \vec{r}$ is always zero.

Comment: ok! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\vec B$ is a constant vector, then we have

$$\begin{align}
 \nabla \left(\frac{\vec B\cdot \vec r}{r^3}\right)&=\nabla \left(\frac{ B_r}{r^2}\right)\\\\
&=B_r\nabla\left(\frac1{r^2}\right)+\frac1{r^2}\underbrace{\nabla (B_r)}_{=0}\\\\
&=B_r \left(-\frac{2\vec r}{r^4}\right)
\end{align}$$

Hence, we have

$$\vec r\times \nabla \left(\frac{\vec B\cdot \vec r}{r^3}\right)=0$$

Comment: Thank you! I think i get it now!

Comment: Hi again! I tried to figure out the notation Br but I still don't understand. And how  r^3 became r^2? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome my pleasure.

Comment: Note that $B_r=\frac{\vec r}{r}\cdot \vec B=\hat r\cdot \vec B$ and $\frac{\vec r}{r^3}=\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$

Comment: @Bella As you are new to this site, thought of letting you know. If this answer helped you, you could accept it by using the tick mark. If you cannot figure out how, this might help -  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287.

Comment: @mathlover Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bella Hi and Happy New Year. Please let me know how I can improve my answer and feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit of course. ;-)